# lemmatization of german words (Capital letters and lower case letters)

Tags: r, text-mining, capitalization, lemmatization, tolower

I would like to lemmatize a list of German words, including nouns and verbs. The struggle here is that this implies words beginning with capital letters and others with lower case letters. Until now I worked with a lookup list. Here, the sample

```
lookup_list <- 
  data.frame(
  cbind(
  c("mache","tust","Tuns","Reisen","genaue","genauer","pflanze","Pflanzen","reise"),
                     c("machen","tuen","Tun","Reise","genau","genau","pflanzen","Pflanze","reisen")
)
)
names(lookup_list) <- c("word","lemma")

Text2Lemmatize <- "mache tust Tuns Reisen genaue genauer pflanze Pflanzen reise"
```

The problem is that '''lemmatize()''' ignores the word in the list that begin with capital letters.

```
lemmatize_strings(Text2Lemmatize, lookup_list)

> lemmatize_strings(Text2Lemmatize, lookup_list)
[1] "machen tuen Tuns Reisen genau genau pflanzen Pflanzen reisen"
```

Can anybody help me out with this little problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want lemmatization of German words or text I advice using udpipe.

```
library(udpipe)

# download german ud model
ud_model <- udpipe_download_model("german")
ud_model <- udpipe_load_model(ud_model)

Text2Lemmatize <- "mache tust Tuns Reisen genaue genauer pflanze Pflanzen reise"

x <- udpipe_annotate(ud_model, Text2Lemmatize)
x <- as.data.frame(x)

x[, c("token", "lemma", "upos")]

     token            lemma upos
1    mache             mach PRON
2     tust            tusen VERB
3     Tuns             Twir PRON
4   Reisen     Reise|Reisen NOUN
5   genaue            genau VERB
6  genauer            genau  ADJ
7  pflanze           pflanz  ADJ
8 Pflanzen Pflanze|Pflanzen NOUN
9    reise           reisen VERB
```

Works better when it is actual text, taken from wikipedia:

> "Das Matterhorn ist einer der höchsten Berge der Alpen. Wegen seiner
> markanten Gestalt und seiner Besteigungsgeschichte ist das Matterhorn
> einer der bekanntesten Berge der Welt. Für die Schweiz ist es ein
> Wahrzeichen und eine der meistfotografierten Touristenattraktionen."

```
german_text

x <- udpipe_annotate(ud_model, german_text)
x <- as.data.frame(x)

# show first 10 results
head(x[, c("token", "lemma", "upos")], 10)
                   token                 lemma  upos
1                    Das                   der   DET
2             Matterhorn            Matterhorn PROPN
3                    ist                  sein   AUX
4                  einer                   ein  PRON
5                    der                   der   DET
6               höchsten                  hoch   ADJ
7                  Berge                  Berg  NOUN
8                    der                   der   DET
9                  Alpen                   Alp  NOUN
10                     .                     . PUNCT
```

If it is wordstemming you need, then use quanteda. It works a lot better with non-English languages.

```
library(quanteda)

my_toks <- tokens(Text2Lemmatize)
my_toks_stemmed <- tokens_wordstem(my_toks, language = "de")
my_toks_stemmed
Tokens consisting of 1 document.
text1 :
[1] "mach"   "tust"   "Tun"    "Reis"   "genau"  "genau"  "pflanz" "Pflanz" "reis"
```